# Error: Server Error while uploading file to mysql using org.apache.commons.upload

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-commons

I am trying to upload a word doc file in MySQL database in a Google app engine application. I am using org.apache.commons.upload to upload file.i have tried so many variations in my code but it every time it gives me same error.

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

i can't figure out what exactly i am doing wrong.please help me to find whats wrong.here's my code:

jsp file:

uploadServlet:-

```
package com.example.prototype3;


 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;

 import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class uploadServlet extends HttpServlet  {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
    Connection conn;
     PreparedStatement ps;
     String url = null;
    try
    {
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
                SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
              // Connecting from App Engine.
              // Load the class that provides the "jdbc:google:mysql://"
              // prefix.
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
              url ="jdbc:google:mysql://vikram-dalvi:data-vault/smartvault? user=root";
            } 
         conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload sfu  = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            List<FileItem> items = sfu.parseRequest(req);
            FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);

         InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
         ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into folders (file) values (?)  where username='vikram' and folder='myfolder'");
         ps.setBlob(1, is); 
         ps.executeUpdate();
         //out.println("<html><head></head><body>file uploaded  successfully</body></html>");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println("<html><head></head><body>"+e+"</body></html>");
    }
  }
  }
```

Stacktrace:-

```
W 11:08:38.407 Error for /uploadServlet
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload
    at com.example.prototype3.uploadServlet.doPost(uploadServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
F 11:08:38.409 Uncaught exception from servlet
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload
    at com.example.prototype3.uploadServlet.doPost(uploadServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: update--> it appears that error goes away after commenting        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload sfu  = new ServletFileUpload(factory); and related code lines...

Comment: depending on how large your file is and how long it takes for the upload and forward you might run into issues with the 30 seconds run time limitation in front end instances in App Engine.

Comment: @konqi  for test purpose i;m uploading an empty word doc file..but the problem is appearing at the declaration of DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

Comment: I see. Could be that the apapche commons fileupload is not supported by appengine. The App Engine way would be to use this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob . And probably do the "real" upload in a task queue. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: @konqi i tried the blobstore..its not helpful to me..because i want to store my file in google cloud sql waith other user information...

Comment: I don't see an issue there. You can update a row in SQL as often as you like. My idea was: Upload the file to blob store, then trigger a task queue in your Servlet to do the upload from blob store to cloud sql. Actually: If you don't have to for some reason I'd store file in Cloud Storage and only store a reference to the file in Cloud SQL. That way you don't exceed you cloud sql database size.

Comment: Why don't you post the stacktrace error you can get on the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) of your app (Monitoring--> Logs)

Comment: @Layo i have updated the question with stacktrace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The particular exception message is telling you that the mentioned class is missing in the classpath. You need to have the [commons-fileupload.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi) in the /WEB-INF/lib.

And indeed, Commons FileUpload has Commons IO as a dependency. You need to download and drop [commons-io.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) in the /WEB-INF/lib as well.

if you are using Maven, all you have to do is to include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```